# Which phrase is correct, to the extent or to such an extent?

Tags: grammar

To form a true social group or a community that allows us to share our interests, feelings, purposes and thoughts with each other, we need the kind of communication that is educative to [ the extent / such an extent ] that we can have indirect experience and modify our attitudes.

Which phrase is correct, to the extent or to such an extent?    Could you help me clarify it?   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both:

1) We need the kind of communication that is educative **to the extent** that we can have indirect experience and modify our attitudes.

and

2) We need the kind of communication that is educative **to such an extent** that we can have indirect experience and modify our attitudes.

are correct.

Sentence 2) implies an intensification of the adjective "educative", as if we said:

3) We need the kind of communication that is **so** educative that we can have indirect experience and modify our attitudes.

Sentence 1) conveys no such intensification.

Comment: Your explanation really helped me a lot.   I have picked the second one.  I really appreciated it.

Comment: @Deborah You can upvote this answer if you like it. It's a less noisy way of saying "thanks, I appreciate it". :)